# why my LSTM forecasting result in negatives values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, forecasting

this is my LSTM model

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(50), input_shape=(time_step, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')

model.summary()
```

I don't know why when I run it sometimes result in negative values
I read in a question where people recommending using "relu" activation, but in my case it didn't help it still produce negative values, plus now I can't use cuDNN so it took astronomically longer

I have tried relu activaiton it still produce negative values, and now it run slower because it can't utilize cuDNN

Comment: Relu should be used in the Dense layer, you probably used it in the LSTM layer which is not what was expected.